# CodeIgniter rewrite URL: catch 404's but ignore specific folder and file type

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In my CodeIgniter application, I use a specific procedure to catch and handle 404's. That's the way I want it to be. I've come up with this .htaccess file to match my needs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Wich works great, except for one major problem. **It redirects** kind of.. **everything**. Say, for example, that my final output references to a .css or .js file that doesn't exists. This will cause my **application** to **re run everything** once again, when it actually doesn't need to.

My solution to this would be to **ignore the `static` folder** (root of my project -- same folder as `index.php`), and **every `.css/.js` file**. However, I don't really know how to implement this, so any directions or suggestions that'd point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `static` folder in relation to your htaccess file? If you htaccess file sitting in your webserver's document root?

Comment: @JonLin the static folder is in the same folder as the .htaccess and index.php file :-). That is, in the projects "root".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(static|(.*)\.css|(.*)\.js)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Adding this line tells .htaccess to **not** process static directory contents.

Comment: Great! Just another thing, how to, in addition to the static folder, make it ignore js/css files? Thanks for your answer! Oh, and would it be proper to add this line at the beginning of the module-if-statement?

Comment: Try making `static` as `static|(.*)\.css|(.*)\.js`

Comment: Thanks! And this should be put as the first line of the if-statement?